# Get MySQL results of parent with both children and children detail counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count, parent-child, children

So, I have a parent table, that has children records, who at the same time have details (3 level parenting tables). I need to get the parent names, with their respective children and children_detail COUNTs.

**parent**

- id_parent
- name

**children**

- id_child
- id_parent
- name

**children_detail**

- id_detail
- id_child
- description

This works until the second level:

```
SELECT parent.id_parent, parent.name,
COUNT(pos.id_pos) AS q
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN children ON children.id_parent = parent.id_parent
GROUP BY parent.id_parent ORDER BY parent.name
```

How can I also get the third level count in the same SELECT? Thanks!

Comment: How big is the table? You could use a sub-query if its relatively small...

Comment: It's not that big. parent (10), children (100), detail (1000) ... those numbers won't be growing too much. I tried your approach with this, didn't work: `SELECT parent.id_parent, parent.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children WHERE children.id_parent = parent.id_parent) AS q1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children_detail WHERE children_detail.id_child = children.id_child) AS q2 FROM parent`

Comment: No, you'd still need to keep the join for the second-level. One sec, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I think my first query might be broken but check my edit. That second one should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your tables are not large, try using a sub-query:

```
SELECT parent.id_parent, parent.name,
COUNT(pos.id_pos) AS q,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children_detail cd WHERE cd.id_child = children.id_child) as cdc
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN children ON children.id_parent = parent.id_parent
GROUP BY parent.id_parent ORDER BY parent.name
```

### Edit

Sorry, the following one should also work:

```
SELECT parent.id_parent, parent.name,
  COUNT(pos.id_pos) AS q,
  COUNT(cdc.id_detail) as cdc
FROM parent
  LEFT JOIN children ON children.id_parent = parent.id_parent
  LEFT JOIN children_detail cdc on cdc.id_child = children.id_child
GROUP BY parent.id_parent, parent.name
ORDER BY parent.name
```

### Edit 2

If all else fails, you can use two sub-queries (very bad practice but should be fine for tables of your size):

```
SELECT parent.id_parent, parent.name,
  COUNT(pos.id_pos) AS q,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children_detail cd WHERE cd.id_child IN (SELECT cc.id_child FROM children cc where cc.id_parent = c.id_parent)) as cdc
FROM parent
  LEFT JOIN children c ON c.id_parent = parent.id_parent
GROUP BY parent.id_parent 
ORDER BY parent.name
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution helped me a lot. As long as the tables don't have too many records, it can work just fine.